# Error while executing post request in spring mvc

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

While Executing the following post request in postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/FinalSmsApi/rest/requestSms/hello
```

with parameter username,password and phone . 
I am getting the following error :

```
HTTP Status 415: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method
```

This is the controller:

```
@RestController
public class MainController1 {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public void Register(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
                         @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
                         @RequestParam(value = "phone") String phone) {...}
}
```

Using Spring 4 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTTP Status 415: The server refused this request...

This means that your endpoint is **not able** to process the passed `Request Body`. This error have two main reasons: either you did **not** specify what is the type of your request body or you passed an invalid data.

By Adding `Content-Type` header to your request headers, this problem would be solved:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

And also, you're not capturing request body in your `public void Register(..)` method. If you're planning to go this way, it's better to drop the `consumes` attribute and pass all the parameters with `Query Parameters`, as you did.

The other approach is to define a resource class like:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phone;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then change your controller to capture the request body, like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void Register(@RequestBody User user) {...}
```

And finally, send a `JSON` representation along with your request:

```
curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"username": "", "password": "", "phone": ""}' http://localhost:8080/hello
```

Comment: i am planning to use consumes, whats the alternative what should i add in the method

Comment: With your current arrangement, using `consumes` is totally useless, since you have not any body attached to the request.

Comment: Still its showing an error,Required String parameter 'username' is not present,The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Try this: `http://localhost:8080/FinalSmsApi/rest/requestSms/hello?username=something&password=secret&phone=09125625`

Comment: Showing a warning:Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: I haven't created a User class , and since i am using Spring 4 , @Response Body isn't required i guess

Comment: Read the spring documentation for more info. I guess your problem is solved.